# The chromedriver.exe file does not exist in the current directory

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium for the first time. I came across this issue after I ran my first test. It's basically telling me that my chromedriver executable does not exist in my current directory. What do I need to do? Below are the steps I took to install it, atleast that is what I thought.

[image]

I installed it through Package Manager Console and then I verified the installation:

[image]

And I also did put the Selenium WebDriver executable in the location where the Google Chrome browser is present. This is not my projects directory. 
[image]

This is the directory for my project and the executable is inside my bin. 
[image]

Comment: Could you try using the `Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver` package instead? That always works for me. Uninstall Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver first and clean the bin dir.

Comment: @PrabG I did, but I am getting the same issue.

Comment: What version is your actual ChromeDriver. Also is there a reason the name shows as 'chromedriver.exe' in your folder? Mine is named 'chromedriver' - it's still an exe type

Comment: @PrabG it is version ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30.  that's how it appears after downloading it.  I had to extract it from a zip file.

Comment: @PrabG Update: Issue was solved. 
I had to declare the driver within the test function feature 
and use the driver.navigate().goto

Answer (score 2):

I use below method to solve the same problem.

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\Temp2");
```

you need to download ChromeDriver.exe from [Google site](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) then put in on some folder of your PC.

I did not have chances to test standard share drive or [environment variable path](https://www.techjunkie.com/environment-variables-windows-10/) , but i will assume it will work as well when you instruct the code point to the right path as above.